# CheckBox checking and unchecking animation is taking time

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

When user click on Checkbox, Checkbox is getting checked after 3 seconds because of large amount of data is getting loaded by LoadShowGuidData() method which i am calling inside ShowGuid() method using "this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke()" which is not effective to solve the problem. **what i want is checkbox should get checked immediately after user click and then data should be loaded.**

- XAML Code:

```
 <DockPanel Margin="2">
     <CheckBox Content="{x:Static p:Resources.checkBoxShowGUID}" Margin="2,0" 
     IsChecked="{Binding ShowGuidIsChecked,IsAsync=True,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
     Command="{Binding ShowGuidCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
 </DockPanel>
```

- ViewModel of the UserControl:

```
        public ICommand ShowGuidCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new ControlCommand<object>(this.ShowGuid, null);
            }
        }

        public void ShowGuid(object variable)
        {
            string errMsg = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                if (!this.DataLayerLocal.CheckManagerRunning())
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
                this.LoadShowGuidData(this.ShowGuidIsChecked)));

            }
            catch (CustomException cex)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg))
                {
                    DisplayMessageBox(errMsg, Properties.Resources.ControlsCaption);
                }
            }           
        }

        public void LoadShowGuidData(bool checkBoxStatus)
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
            string errMsg = string.Empty;
            try
            {               
                this.varValues = this.DataLayerLocal.GetVariablesInformation(this.ProcedurePath, 
                checkBoxStatus ? 1 : 0, out errMsg);
                this.NewLineRemover();
                this.VariableList = this.varValues;
                this.Sort();
            }
            catch (CustomException cex)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg))
                {
                    DisplayMessageBox(errMsg, Properties.Resources.ControlsCaption);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should probably look at async methods, so your event can keep going and at the same time you data get loaded.

Comment: @AnantJain: Why are you calling `BeginInvoke`? The command is invoked on the UI thread. You should execute `LoadShowGuidData` on a background thread using `Task.Run`.

Comment: Thats what i want to know how to use Task in this scenario.I am using BeginInvoke just to show that it is not working as mentioned in the question.